# Why is No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lockerror prompted？

Tags: c, linux, debian

I want to check the use of the **pthread_mutex_lock** function, so I execute the command  **man pthread_mutex_lock**, the result appears **No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock**.
I checked the information on the Internet and said that there was a **No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock** prompt, need to install **manpages-posix-dev**.

So I'm ready to install **manpages-posix-dev**（I execute the command: **apt-get install manpages-posix-dev**）, but **E: Unable to locate package manpages-posix-dev** prompts me again. Why?I'm using the debian 10 system.

```
gyz@debian:~$ man  pthread_mutex_lock
No manual entry for pthread_mutex_lock
gyz@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package manpages-posix-dev
gyz@debian:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
gyz@debian:~$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
gyz@debian:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 
SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07)
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/167521/where-is-the-man-page-for-pthread-mutex-lock

Comment: @user253751 good, thank you.  I execute the command : apt-get install glibc-doc.

Answer (score 0):

(Even though the question is tagged Debian it appears in generic search results)

The answer for Fedora is that Fedora has [removed posix manpages entirely](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/man-pages/blob/rawhide/f/man-pages.spec#_106); you need to download/install 'manually' (there's a make installer included in the archive) from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/man-pages-posix/

(Thanks to [redditors](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/xqt2lv/how_to_get_posix_man_pages_now_that_fedora_has/))